Linear Algebra - obtaining as many y's given as many x's
I am trying to solve a problem (simplified) that essentially wants to do the following.
It has been 15 years since my last linear algebra course, so I am hoping that my intuition is right.

This is a table that shows a relationship where
$$x_i = ay_i+by_{i-1}$$
$a$ and $b$ are known.
Further, $y_0, y_{-1}, ...$ are not available.
Here, it is clear that $y_1$ and perhaps $y_2$ is not solvable, but intuitively the latter numbers $y_{11}$ and $y_{12}$ should be solvable.
Or is this a situation where because $y_0$ is not available, the entire y is unsolvable?
ex), $a= 0.25$, $b = 0.75$

My statistical background tells me that there should be a "likely value" that $y_0$ can be chosen as since we have 1 degree of freedom in this system, so once we choose that all $y_i$s will cascade into a "likely solution".
For example, we do have a real life case like this.

An approach I would consider doing using this would come to the conclusion that the weighted average of ${y_i+y_{i-1} \over {x_i}} \approx 2$
This would allow me to use
$$y_0 \approx 19886 - y_1$$
as an additional information which allows me to get a table

I vaguely recall learning something that indicates that there is a method that does not rely on having an actual which gave me a guidance towards why sort of numbers $y_i$ approximately look like.
Essentially I have 2 questions.

Is this truly unsolvable without additional information?
If not the case, what is the approach?

Thank you so much and I appreciate your bright insights.

In your example table there are 12 $x$ values, hence 12 equations, and 13 unknowns ($y_0 ... y_{12}$). As you wrote, this system has 1 degree of freedom, which means 1 of your variables (say, $y_0$) can take any value and the other unknowns can be calculated as functions of it.

Yeah that's what I thought.  I guess I have to find a balance approach on what extra condition I have to use for the last piece to make it work.  Thanks!

What are $x$ and $y$ variables in your case? Depending on their nature and possible recursive relations we might be able to use time series analysis.
